# HelpPath in AEM6.1 Touch UI Dialogs

Tags: aem

Along the top of Touch UI dialogs are a series of buttons. I need to configure the help button (leftmost) so it points to the documentation for the component. I see that helppath is the property name I should use according to [this example from Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-component.html). But it's not working, and instead always points to https://www.adobe.com/go/aem6_1_docs which is not what we need.

[image: AEM Touch UI Component or Page Dialog]

Here is the cq:dialog http://localhost:4502/apps/blah/components/events/cq%3Adialog.2.json
I've tried both helpPath (works in Classic UI)and helppath, but it is not working in the Touch UI. Any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks!

> { jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured", helpPath:
>   "/content/blah/en/aem-support/events.html",
>   helppath:
>   "/content/blah/en/aem-support/events.html",
>   sling:resourceType: "cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog", content: {
>   jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured", sling:resourceType:
>   "granite/ui/components/foundation/container", layout: {
>   jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured", type: "nav", sling:resourceType:
>   "granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs" }, items: {
>   jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured" } } }

looking at the [code](http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/dialog.jsp) it seems pretty well hard-coded...

```
private AttrBuilder getHelpAttrs(SlingHttpServletRequest req, Config cfg, XSSAPI xssAPI, I18n i18n) {
String url = i18n.getVar("https://www.adobe.com/go/aem6_1_docs");

AttrBuilder attrs = new AttrBuilder(req, xssAPI);
attrs.add("type", "button");
attrs.addClass("coral-MinimalButton cq-dialog-header-action cq-dialog-help");
attrs.addHref("data-href", url);
attrs.add("title", i18n.get("Help"));

return attrs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have used 2 times "helpPath" property. Kindly add once under cq:dialog node and check. For me its working fine.